# fetch previous, current and next record where it meets certain condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to solve an issue where I need to find the previous,current and next record where the query matches certain condition. In the example image below I am interested in only records where pattern_id=23587462 (can be multiple), and it the previous machine_id = next machine_id, then fetch the 3 records.

```
select SL.*, row_number() over (PARTITION BY Machine_id Order by machine_id, SS2k) as M
from SL
where pattern_id in (23587462,2879003)
```

I am expecting these records plus the previous and the next record too

[image]

Update:- with the help of @shawnt00 and @SelVazi, I used their syntax/code and have a modified version as below,

```
  with cte as (Select SL.*, lead(machine_id,1) over (order by machine_id) as lead_mid, lead(pattern_id,1) over (order by machine_id) as lead_pid,
            lag(machine_id,1) over (order by machine_id) as lag_mid, lag(pattern_id,1) over (order by machine_id) as lag_pid,
            Case 
                when pattern_id in (23587462) then 'Current'
                when lead_pid in (23587462) and machine_id=lead_mid then 'Source'
                when lag_pid in (23587462) and machine_id=lag_mid then 'Loss'
            End as sourceloss
            from SL)
    Select * from cte 
    where sourceloss is not Null;
```

Comment: Can you share your table definition ?

Comment: Hi SelVazi, these 3 columns are just integers, and yes the SS2K are sort of unique as these are just seconds converted to numbers. I will try the belwo solution now thank you:)

Comment: Can any of these overlap by having the same pattern id within the group of three?

Comment: No the pattern_id in ColB can't overlap. but Machine_id has to be the same in those 3 segments

Comment: I guess I should clarify. Is that an impossible scenario? Or is that just not a valid match?

Answer (score 1):

This is a working solution if the ss2k is unique and take on considération if the machine_id should be the same for pervious current and next record for the selected pattern_id :

```
with cte as (
  select *, lag(ss2k) over (Order by id) as source,
  lead(ss2k) over (Order by id) as Loss
  from mytable
),
cte2 as (
  select c.id, t.machine_id, c.pattern_id, c.ss2k, c.machine_id as currentMachine, row_number() over (order by c.id) as rn
  from cte c
  inner join mytable t on t.ss2k = c.ss2k or t.ss2k = c.source or t.ss2k = c.loss
  where t.pattern_id = 23587462
  order by id
),
cte3 as (
  select c.id, c.machine_id, c.pattern_id, c.ss2k, 
  case when rn%3 = 1 then 'source'
       when rn%3 = 2 then 'current'
       when rn%3 = 0 then 'loss' 
  end as status,
  rn,
  (rn-1)/3+1 groupIds
  from cte2 c
  where c.currentMachine = c.machine_id
)
select c.machine_id, c.pattern_id, c.ss2k, c.status
from cte3 c
inner join (
  select groupids
  from cte3
  group by groupids
  having count(1) = 3
) as s on s.groupids = c.groupids
```

First `cte` to get previous and next record using two window functions :

`Lag()` function to get data of a previous row from the current row.

`Lead()` function to get data of a previous row from the current row.

`cte2` to get the machine_id of the previous and next records.

`cte3` to group records by group of 3 records(previous, current and next), then with a join we get only data from group of 3 records (if length is less than 3 that means one of the records is not in the same machine so ignore the whole group).

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/q07AY8mu)

Comment: This is sort of working, but its just giving me output for 1 pattern_id. But I want to get the previous and the next row where pattern_id=23587462. So for example the previous roecord can have the pattern_id=300 and the next row can have pattern_id=8796, but the current row pattern_id should be 23587462.

Comment: I have fixed it, a small change was needed, can you check

Comment: The "current" record should have the same pattern_id=23587462, but in this updated instance I am getting different pattern_id's

Comment: We get current from column `ss2k` (`72566103` and `72566103`) where pattern_id= 23587462,and we have two rows as result : (4,1,23587462, `72566103`)( 2,23587462, `7256107`)

Comment: I'm not sure about the differing pattern ids. But this query can't possibly work with even the sample data which has two sets of matches under the same 802 machine. The query partitions the row numbering by machine and only handles those with `rn` values 1-3.

Comment: @shawnt00 I have added an other option where the machine_id partition ignored.

Comment: @SelVazi Now that's just assuming that all the machine ids are in sequence with the time values (ss2k). It doesn't verify anything about them having come from the same machine so it only returns results because the test data is arranged that way.

Comment: The original table is ordered in Asc by machine_id,SS2K. So I am trying to find a logic where after this arrangement, it it hits the 1st record with pattern_id=23587462, and the machine_ids are same for current,current-1 and current+1 records, then as long as the top and bottom pattern_id's are different than current then I will need those 3 records, then it should continue fetching more records with this same logic for the entire table. There is nowhere I can attch the file, else I would have sent an excel file where I have done it manually, but need to do this while fetching the data in sql

Comment: I have updated my answer to take on concideration that machine_ids should  be the same

Answer (score 1):

A naive `lead/lag()` method will work here without requiring any joins. It does require that there be three rows in the matching "group" of rows.

```
with data as (select *, 23587462 as PATTERN from T), grp as (
    select *,
        case PATTERN
            when lead(Pattern_ID) over (partition by Machine_ID order by SS2K)
            then lead(SS2K)       over (partition by Machine_ID order by SS2K)
            when Pattern_ID
            then SS2K
            when lag(Pattern_ID)  over (partition by Machine_ID order by SS2K)
            then lag(SS2K)        over (partition by Machine_ID order by SS2K)
        end as grp,
        case PATTERN
            when lead(Pattern_ID) over (partition by Machine_ID order by SS2K)
            then -1
            when Pattern_ID
            then 0
            when lag(Pattern_ID)  over (partition by Machine_ID order by SS2K)
            then 1
         end as idx
    from data
), runs as (
   select *, count(*) over (partition by grp) as grp_length
   from grp
   where grp is not null
)
select *,
    case idx when -1 then 'Source' when 0 then 'Current' when 1 then 'Loss' end as D
from runs
where grp_length = 3
order by Machine_ID, SS2K;
```

This does have problems if there are overlapping sets of rows. Take a look at the third set in the example link below for an example of that scenario (with `Machine_ID` of all 9's.)

Another approach eliminates that problem by examining each set of three consecutive rows. In that way the overlaps are no longer a problem. It's not clear though how you'd want to label those rows:

```
with runs as (
    select *,
        case when
            Pattern_ID = 23587462 and
            min(Machine_ID) over (
                partition by Machine_ID order by SS2K
                rows between 1 preceding and 1 following) =
            max(Machine_ID) over (
                partition by Machine_ID order by SS2K
                rows between 1 preceding and 1 following) and
            count(*) over (
                partition by Machine_ID
                order by SS2K rows between 1 preceding and 1 following) = 3
            then 1 end as flg
    from T
), tagged as (
    select *,
        case when 1 in (lag(flg)  over (order by SS2K),
                        flg,
                        lead(flg) over (order by SS2K)) then 1 end as keep
    from runs
)
select * from tagged where keep = 1
order by Machine_ID, SS2K;
```

Both of the queries do assume that `SS2K` is unique for the relevant rows adjacent to the matches.

https://dbfiddle.uk/7YU9IB1h

Comment: Hey, so SS2k is not unique. but the initial table has been ordered by Asc on machine_id and SS2k. so if we look at row 3681:3683 in the screenshot image in the question, we see that for the interested pattern_id in 23587462, the machine_id's are same as current row, previous and next row. But the SS2k are different.

Comment: @  Kano, you need to be able to define the order of rows if there is going to be a concept of "previous" and "next". Now looking closer at the sample data I do see that you've got the data sorted.

Comment: @Kano, I've adjusted the query. Perhaps that will be sufficient.

Comment: unfortunately this is still giving me a lot more data. I have attached the sample data file below, for which ideally it should just fetch me these records from a total of 66 rows, 4-6,12-14,17-19,27-29,33-35,38-40

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/CSw9tYJO

Comment: @Kano, I ran both queries and got only the 9 rows that you've highlighted as good matches. Most of those rows have a different pattern id.

Comment: yeah I just ran the code in your dbfiddle and it works! I must be doing something wrong in the original query in snowflake. Thank you very much, this definitely works. Thank you:)